# lsof and limits open file

Tags: linux, system, limits, lsof

Maybe someone make clear for me, about how work system limits:
/etc/security/limits.conf

```
#<domain>   <type>  <item>  <value>
mysql   soft    nofile      2048
mysql   hard    nofile      2048
```

nofile - max number of open file descriptors

**lsof -u mysql | wc -l
3450**
This number is larger than 2048

Comment: Duplication of question from unix.stackexchange: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108603/do-changes-in-etc-security-limits-conf-require-a-reboot

Comment: I revived this question, but this does not help. I have rebooted the system and all sessions with old parameters were closed. And the system still has larger count than it in /limits.conf